# How to customize heatmap color on pre decided constraint values?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, heatmap

I am working on heatmap and situation is i have to change the  color of heat map marker on the basis of some constraints and the color should change according to those  basic constraints values. 
My approach is this:

```
function HeatMapCreate(heatMapData, GetNumberFromString)
    //  heatMapData contains the object of LatLng and get number is the   constraint
    // which contains a number on the basis of which we set color
    // (green if 48 and red if 36 else yellow)
        {
            var gradient;
            var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer(
                        {
                            data: heatMapData,
                        });
            heatmap.setOptions({ radius: heatmap.get('20') });

            if (GetNumberFromString == 36)
            {
                gradient = [For red color]
            }
            else if(GetNumberFromString == 48)
            {
             gradient = [For green color]
            }
            else
            {
                gradient = [For yellow color]

            }

            heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        }
```

How to achieve this ? **I am bit surprised there is not a single answer (even comment) to this answer, that makes me feel either question is too bad or it is impossible to have heatmap markers of different color ?** Could some one please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Your penultimate line of code looks like you've just copied it from [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) which demonstrates toggling between two gradients.

```
heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
```

It's not the best example to be honest; they're really either setting the gradient to the one they've specified, or setting it to null, i.e. defaulting the gradient back to Google's default colour scheme.

Instead what you want to do is have all your own gradients defined already, and then toggle between them in response to the `GetNumberFromString` value.  Here's an untested example.  I've gone with a 'blue' colour for the last one, just because it was easier!  You probably want to come up with your own set of colours; I expect there's online tools that can produce these for you quite quickly, e.g. http://angrytools.com/gradient/

```
function HeatMapCreate(heatMapData, GetNumberFromString) {
    var gradients = {
        red: [
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        green: [
            'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)',
            'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)'
        ],
        blue: [
            'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)'
        ]
    };
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: heatMapData,
        radius: 20,
        map: map
    });

    switch (GetNumberFromString) {
        case 36:
            heatmap.set('gradient', gradients['red']);
            break;
        case 48:
            heatmap.set('gradient', gradients['green']);
            break;
        default:
            heatmap.set('gradient', gradients['blue']);
            break;

    }
}
```

See also: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer

Comment: Thanks.. let me try will mark as answer soon as it works.

Comment: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side at line where we do "'red' = [......]"

Comment: i solved this problem by remiving single quotes from red, green and blue but now the problem is it always execute the default condition of switch condition even i see  GetNumberFromString value 36 and 48 as well on console.log . What could be the possible reason ? i also tried the covering in single quotes ('48') but still do not work.

Comment: Oops sorry, basic JS error on my part, should have been `gradients = { key: value, ... }` instead of `gradients = [key = value, ...]`

Comment: What is `GetNumberFromString`, where does it come from?  Is it a string (`'36'`), an integer (`36`) or a float (`36.0`), or something else?

Comment: Also those rgba values I've given  you are probably all wrong, I had the opacity in the wrong column.  I'll try and find some proper examples; or you might have more luck figuring those out yourself to match your own requirements.

Comment: I've updated my gradients, each example just goes from zero-opacity to full-opacity.  Possibly these might not work too well, you maybe need to define more individual values for each gradient.  See http://angrytools.com/gradient/

Comment: yes it worked for me wheni done parseInt(GetNumberFromString) and kept below integer values in case conditions. But the problem is it changes the color of all the map not just of that LatLong object whichis under execution.For eg. if the current execution of code is in 36 case then it makes all the heat map red (even i had 48 and default beofre which are supposed to be remain green and blue) they also becomes red.

Comment: yes it worked for me wheni done parseInt(GetNumberFromString) and kept below integer values in case conditions. But the problem is it changes the color of all the map not just of that LatLong object whichis under execution.For eg. if the current execution of code is in 36 case then it makes all the heat map red (even i had 48 and default beofre which are supposed to be remain green and blue) they also becomes red. see this when value is 36 it makes all green http://prntscr.com/7jsq2s

Comment: Can you show more code, how are you calling the HeatMapCreate function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement different colors with a single heat map. You will have to use an individual heatmap layer for each color you intend to show based on the GetNumberFromString functions return value.

Check out the code below.

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.785091, -73.968285),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  codeAddress("10001", 'rgba(1, 1, 0, 0)', 'rgba(1, 1, 0, 1)');
  codeAddress("10002", 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0)', 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)');
  codeAddress("10003", 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
  codeAddress("10004", 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)');
  codeAddress("10005", 'rgba(153, 0, 153, 0)', 'rgba(153, 0, 153, 1)');
  codeAddress("10006", 'rgba(1, 1, 0, 0)', 'rgba(1, 1, 0, 1)');

  function codeAddress(zip, rgbA1, rgbA2) {
    //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': zip
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var hotSpot = results[0].geometry.location;

        var heatMapZip = [{
            location: hotSpot
          }

        ];

        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: heatMapZip,
          radius: 20,
          dissapating: false
        });

        var gradient = [rgbA1, rgbA2];
        heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
        heatmap.setMap(map);

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```